# How easy is it for a baby yellow bellied slider to obtain an internal injury?

Tags: turtles

Okay so today, I was moving my baby to a different location. I had him in his smaller travel tank, I set it in the sun so he could bask while I set up his big tank. While I was doing this I took my eyes off of him, and my uncles dog had snagged him out of his tank  and I am not sure if he chewed or whatever on him. But I rescued my turtle as soon as I realized. I checked him over and he doesn’t have any external injuries. Like no, chew marks, no punctures, no blood, nothing raw looking. So on the outside he looks perfectly  fine... I mean aside the fact that he’s in complete shock. Which was another question, could he die from shock... I’m just so worried and I feel awful bc he’s my baby. I just need some words of advice. What to watch for from here on out... what to expect if he does have any internal injuries. Anything. Like has this happened to anybody before me and their turtle survived?

Comment: Go an take your pet to the Vet. The internet is a wonderful place, but proving good medical care for pets it not among it's strong suits.